# How would I write an event to click and drag to scroll horizontally and vertically in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to work out how to be able to click within my main container and drag to scroll the content both left and right as well as up and down.  I have it working for the left and right part but I am unsure why it isn't working for the up and down, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
<!-- Bring in my stylesheet -->    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/assets/css/portfolio-a.css">

     <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>

     <div class="container-fluid main-container" id="main-container">


       <div class="midball"></div>
       <div class="foreball"></div>
       <div class="backball"></div>

       <span  class="my_story">My Story</span>

       

       <div  class="triangle_2"></div>
       <div  class="triangle_3"></div>

       <span  class="languages-header">Languages</span>







<div  class="square_1"></div>

<div  class="square_2"></div>





<span  class="contact">Contact</span>
<span  class="first_name">First Name</span>
<span  class="last_name">Last Name</span>
<span  class="phone_number">Phone Number</span>
<span  class="message">Message</span>
<span  class="email">Email</span>

<div class="contact-me-button-container">
<span  class="contact-me-button">Contact Me</span>
</div>


<div class="my-portrait-container">
<div  class="my-portrait-frame"></div>
<div class="my-image-container">
<div class="my-image">
<div  class="my-image-dark"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="front-end-container">
<span  class="front">Front</span>
<span  class="front-end">End</span>
</div>



<!-- <div  class="ellipse_20"></div>
<div  class="ellipse_21"></div> -->
</div>

<div class="contact-form-button-container">
<span  class="contact-form-button">Submit </span>
</div>

<div  class="first-name-container"></div>
<div  class="last-name-container"></div>
<div  class="phone-number-container"></div>
<div  class="email-container"></div>
<div  class="message-content-container"></div>

<div  class="blob_1"></div>
<div  class="blob_2"></div>
<div  class="blob_3"></div>

<div  class="triangle_1"></div>

<!-- Sidebar  -->
<div class="sidebar-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<div  class="logo-image-container"></div>
<div  class="logo-text-container"></div>
</div>

<div  class="ellipse_16" id="ellipse_16"></div>

<div class="sidebar-content-container">
<a href="#company-information">    <div  class="logo-image"></div> </a>
<a href="#company-information">    <span  class="webtek-link">WebTek</span></a>
</div>
<a href="#"><span  class="about-me-link">About Me</span></a>
<a href="#">  <span  class="projects-link">Projects</span></a>
<a href="#">  <span  class="languages-link">Languages</span></a>
<a href="#">  <span  class="contact-link">Contact</span></a>
</div>
</div>

<script src="dist/build.js" defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the two above containers, one within the other and I want the sidebar which has the css properties as follows to remain fixed.

```
 .sidebar-container { 
    width: 214px;
    height: 1080px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    }
    
My main-container css is as follows.

.main-container { 
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
width: 1920px;
height: 5460px;
}
#main-container {
cursor: grab;
overflow: auto;
}
```

My JavaScript file has the following code which works but I want the drag to scroll to work up and down and left to right.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     const ele = document.getElementById('main-container');
     ele.style.cursor = 'grab';
 
     let pos = { top: 0, left: 0, x: 0, y: 0 };
 
     const mouseDownHandler = function(e) {
         ele.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
         ele.style.userSelect = 'none';
 
         pos = {
             left: ele.scrollLeft,
             top: ele.scrollTop,
             // Get the current mouse position
             x: e.clientX,
             y: e.clientY,
         };
 
         document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
         document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
     };
 
     const mouseMoveHandler = function(e) {
         // How far the mouse has been moved
         const dx = e.clientX - pos.x;
         const dy = e.clientY - pos.y;
 
         // Scroll the element
         ele.scrollTop = pos.top - dy;
         ele.scrollLeft = pos.left - dx;
     };
 
     const mouseUpHandler = function() {
         ele.style.cursor = 'grab';
         ele.style.removeProperty('user-select');
 
         document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
         document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
     };
 
     // Attach the handler
     ele.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler);
 });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please give us more from the html. If we can recreate to code it's much easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the vertical scroll to work I needed to set the height property for less than the amount the content was using on the page, thank you for taking the time to read my post and question.  I appreciate it.